# What is the use of "&>>" in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I was studying a bash script code where I encountered operator "&>>".
 I didn't understand its use. So, I referred to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html .

It is semantically equivalent to `>> file 2>&1` .

Following is the output from my shell :-

```
# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
# echo "hello" &>> file1
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

and

```
# echo "hello" >> file1 2>&1

# cat file1 

hello
```

Question :- Why am I getting error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '>'` ?

**[EDIT]** :- Bash version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: What version of Bash are you using? Some of these features are only available in newer versions of Bash.

Comment: BTW, this works for me, `bash --version` = 4.1.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because you using an older version of bash (3.2.25).

> Since Bash4, there's `&>>TARGET`, which is equivalent to `>> TARGET 2>&1`.

Source: [Appending redirected output](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#appending_redirected_output)

So, you should take in consideration an upgrade. I use bash version 4.2.45 and `echo "hello" &>> file1` works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

This feature was introduced in bash 4.0 alpha, so it should be available in any bash >= 4.0.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?id=0001803f0b9523c94fa2ede48eaecb047fef4524 -- line 976.

(The original 4.0-alpha changelog mis-reported the operator as `>>&`.  The man page shows the correct `&>>`, and the typo was corrected in 4.1.)